# How to find out what portions of an image is helping CNN to classify it

Tags: python, cnn, feature-selection, image-classification, transfer-learning

I am working on an image classification problem using Transfer learning. Right now, I am getting an accuracy of 75% on train data and 67% in test data. Now I want to understand what portions/parts of the image are being utilized for classification graphically.

Are there any packages that can return a copy of one of the input images with markings on the most useful pixels or parts of the image?

Comment: Yes, you can use integrated gradients.   There are several tutorials online: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/interpretability/integrated_gradients

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the typical approach is to obtain the **saliency map** of the input, which are "heatmaps" of the contribution of each pixel to the final classification.

In [this free online book about Explainable ML](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/pixel-attribution.html), you can find the most relevant approaches to obtain saliency maps, like vanilla gradients, together with other pixel attribution techniques.

[Here](https://www.machinecurve.com/index.php/2019/11/25/visualizing-keras-cnn-attention-saliency-maps/) you can find an end-to-end tutorial on how to implement saliency maps with Keras.